# Доступ к отдельным частям строки в текстовом файле(C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Делаю лабораторную- "Ограничение доступа по скорости набора фразы на клавиатуре".

Допустим в текстовом файле у меня хранятся записи:

- Никита--3--41
- Вася--3--43
- Петя--5--52

Никита-это имя пользователя; 3-номер ключевой фразы(фразы выбираются из другого файла);41-скорость набора фразы

Это данные, которые вводятся  в форме регистрации и сохраняются в текстовый файл.
Для второй формы-формы входа, мне нужно отдельно записать в один ДИНАМИЧЕСКИЙ массив(коллекцию) имена, во второй номера строк,  а в третий-время.
 Как мне реализовать это? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А какой смысл разводить данные по трём массивам? Почему не один список объектов?

Comment: Мне нужно занести имена в ComboBox, например. Номер ключевой фразы использовать как индекс в массиве, чтобы получать эту фразу.
Ну а время-для сравнения с временем, за которое пользователь вводить фразу при входе.
 Мне показалось, что удобнее будет разделить, но это только мои предположения.
 Если есть какие-то идеи и советы, то с радостью выслушаю.

Comment: Разумеется. Заведите объект, который описывает пользователя и его информацию. И список этих объектов. Для показа в комбобоксе можно указать, содержимое какого поля показывать (делается по-разному, в зависимости от вашего графического фреймворка). Плюсы — вам не нужно заботиться о синхронизации трёх списков всё время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если через List. Создаёте класс:

```
class DataSpeed
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string number {get; set;}
    public string time {get; set;}
}
```

И потом в трёхмерный массив:

```
static void Main()
{ 
    List<DataSpeed> DS = new<DataSpeed>();

    StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"D:\1.txt");
    while (true)
    {
         string temp = fs.ReadLine();
         if(temp == null) break;
         DS.Add(new DataSpeed() { name = temp.Split('--')[0], number = temp.Split('--')[1], temp.Split('--')[2] });
    }
}
```

Данные теперь связанны и можно из списка вытаскивать отдельно всё что нужно для того же комбобокса.

Comment: Только вы забыли закрыть `StreamReader`. Ну и вообще он не нужен: `(from line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\1.txt") let parts = line.Split("---") select new DataSpeed() { name = parts[0], number = parts[1], time = parts[2] }).ToList()`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь вам обоим.

Comment: @N.Khlystov: Если вам помогло, не забудьте поставить ответу зелёную галку (слева).

Comment: [Зануда- ON] только массив у вас не трехмерный, а одномерный, с 3-мя полями у каждого элемента, с натяжкой его можно считать двумерным. `StreamReader` надо засунуть в `using`[Зануда-OFF] а в целом примерно как-то так, но можно короче, VladD уже продемонстрировал.